# Why thread stop times are different from when java GC

Tags: garbage-collection

when add PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime to show the thread stop time when GC, we can see the different stop time, like:
2018-05-13T11:15:48.562+0800: 51.190: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.1729628 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000526 seconds
2018-05-13T11:15:48.621+0800: 51.249: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0005166 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0000728 seconds

we can see, the first thread stopped 173ms, but the second one is less than 1 ms. Why they are so different? And what's the exact meaning of the "stop time" (when start counting, and when stop).

If it's the real and accurate time when the thread hung, does it mean one thread has been suspend for a while while other thread is still running when GC?

Answer (score 0):

Option name `-XX+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime` is misleading.
It reports all JVM safepoints (or Stop-the-World pauses).
In addition, GC own logging accounts only GC related time, while safepoint process itself may have little more overhead.

[Here](http://blog.ragozin.info/2012/10/safepoints-in-hotspot-jvm.html) you can find more information about safepoints in HotSpot JVM.